# clarification of G?

Tags: general-topology

> > Let $X$ be a metric space and $f\colon X \rightarrow \mathbb R$ be a continuous function. Let $G = \{ (x , f(x) ) : x \in X \}$ be the  graph of $f$. Then which one is true?

1. $G$ is homeomorphic to $X$
2. $G$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R$
3. $G$ is homeomorphic to $X \times \mathbb R$
4. $G$  is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R \times X$

## My attempt : My answer    None of the option is correct

For option $1)$ Consider $X=(0,1)$ and $f(x)=x$ then $G=\{(x,x):x\in (0,1)\}$  which is a closed set  but $(0,1)$ is not

option $2)$ $X=[0,1]$ which is compact and $f(x)=x$.Its graph is compact but $\mathbb R$ is not.

option $3)$ $f(x)=0$ .Then graph of $f=\{(x,0):x\in \mathbb R\}$ i.e. the $x$ axis .Now remove the point $(0,0)$ from the graph of $f$ ,it becomes disconnected   but $\mathbb R^2\setminus \{(0,0)\}$ is not.

option $4)$.Consider $f(x)=x$ .Then graph of $f=\{(0,y):x\in \mathbb R\}$ i.e. the $y$ axis .Now remove the point $(0,0)$ from the graph of $f$ ,it becomes disconnected   but $\mathbb R^2\setminus \{(0,0)\}$ is not.

Is  my answer  is correct or not correct ?

Pliz tell me

Comment: For (1): $G$ doesn't look very closed to me (in particular: its complement doesn't include a neighbourhood of $(0,0)$, but does include $(0,0)$). The others are fine.

Comment: thanks u  @user3482749.

Comment: 3. and 4. are the "same" because $X \times Y$ and $Y \times X$ are homeomorphic for any two spaces $X,Y$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your counter example for (1) doesn't work for two reasons: because $\{(x,x)\mid x \in (0,1)\} $ is not closed in the plane (it does not contain the limit points $(0,0)$ and $(1,1)$), and moreover, being open or closed are weak conditions to look at, since every space is both open and closed with respect to itself.

Item (1) is actually true, with homeomorphism $$X\ni x\mapsto (x,f(x))\in G $$and inverse $$G\ni (x,y)\mapsto x \in X. $$

Comment: thanks   Ivo  terek